# ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency H

Tags: dataframe, frequency, reindex, pandas-resample

I have a pandas dataframe that I have reindexed to use hourly values.  It is a list of weather observations that was a mix of 3-hourly, hourly, and more-than-once-per-hour data.  Now I am trying to add some columns to calculate and plot the values I need, but I have been getting the odd error I put as my question. In this code, "winter_months" is a list of tuples of date-time-groups and temperatures.

```
    # compute 24-hour rolling mean for winter months
    dfw = pd.DataFrame(winter_months, columns = ('date_time','temp'))
    dfw['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(dfw['date_time'])
    dfw = dfw.set_index('date_time', drop=True).resample('H').mean()
    dfw = dfw.sort_index()
    dfw
```

This returns a lovely dataframe that is just what I wanted:
[beginning of the output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNkbi.png)
with hourly values from 1948 to 2021. The index is now hourly, which is terrific.

```
    dfw.index
    DatetimeIndex(['1948-02-15 06:00:00', '1948-02-15 07:00:00',
           '1948-02-15 08:00:00', '1948-02-15 09:00:00',
           '1948-02-15 10:00:00', '1948-02-15 11:00:00',
           '1948-02-15 12:00:00', '1948-02-15 13:00:00',
           '1948-02-15 14:00:00', '1948-02-15 15:00:00',
           ...
           '2021-03-31 14:00:00', '2021-03-31 15:00:00',
           '2021-03-31 16:00:00', '2021-03-31 17:00:00',
           '2021-03-31 18:00:00', '2021-03-31 19:00:00',
           '2021-03-31 20:00:00', '2021-03-31 21:00:00',
           '2021-03-31 22:00:00', '2021-03-31 23:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date_time', length=641010, freq='H')
```

The problem comes up when I try to create a new date index so that the low temperature data can be grouped within a continuous period of Oct-Mar.

```
    dfw['pretend_winter'] = dfw.index + pd.DateOffset(months=9)
```

ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency H

I  have looked at [ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency MS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715894/valueerror-inferred-frequency-none-from-passed-values-does-not-conform-to-passe)
and [Pandas not able to infer time series frequency, despite proper formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986883/pandas-not-able-to-infer-time-series-frequency-despite-proper-formatting)
and tried the solutions posted there with no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: If I don't resample to an hourly frequency, I am able to use the data offset to create a new "winter" year group.  The reason I want hourly observations is that I am calculating a rolling mean over 24 hours, and am using a minimum of 23 periods to exclude means over missing data.  The 3-hourly observations only have 8 periods in 24 hours, and I am using the resampling to fill those years' data.

Comment: I changed the 9-month date offset to 270 days, and got rid of this error.